# Is it possible to download a file using a Powershell DSC resource from Azure File storage account?

Tags: azure, dsc, azure-storage

I have a file in an Azure File storage. I would like to download it using a DSC resource (`xRemoteFile`, for example).

The Azure File storage gives me an HTTPS url to that file, but it is not directly usable:

[image]

**EDIT 1**

Using SAS:

[image]

Next I am trying to use the SAS URL:

[image]

Still no dice.

**EDIT 2**

As you can see from the snapshots, the SasToken is

```
?sv=2017-07-29&ss=f&srt=o&sp=r&se=2020-05-10T00:41:14Z&st=2018-05-09T16:41:14Z&spr=https&sig=...
```

and the URL is

```
https://***.file.core.windows.net/?sv=2017-07-29&ss=f&srt=o&sp=r&se=2020-05-10T00:41:14Z&st=2018-05-09T16:41:14Z&spr=https&sig=...
```

i.e. the SasToken is appended to `https://***.file.core.windows.net/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't tell from the screenshot if you are, but you need to specify a SaS token. Azure File shares have the ACL set to private and you cannot change that, so you can't download the file anonymously. You need to generate a SaS token for authentication and then use that in your URL.

You can generate a SaS token directly in the Azure portal now.

Comment: Still does not work. I must be misunderstanding something very basic here...

Comment: your URL is wrong, it should be https://name.files.core.windows.net/filename.doc?SaSToken

Comment: Hmm, but this is exactly what I am doing - I updated the post.

Comment: No, your not, your doing file.core.windows.net?sastoken, you have no file name inbetween

Comment: Oh, stupid me. Now I finally get it. Thanks a bunch, it worked.